# How to get all the column of a given row of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following JQuery which adds a row to a table dynamically:

```
var i = 0;
...
i++;
var rowId = "itemEntry" + i + "";

alert(rowId);

var strRowEntry = '<tr id="itemEntry' + i + '"><td class="rowItem">' + $("#itemChoice option:selected").text() +'</td><td class="rowItem">' + priceEach + '</td><td class="rowItem">' + $("#quantity").val() + '</td><td class="rowItem">' + $("#price").val() + '</td><td class="rowItem"><a href="#" onclick="doThis(' + rowId + ');"><img class="deleteRow" src="edit.png" border="0" id="imgEdit" /></a></td></tr>';

$('#itemTable tr:last').after(strRowEntry);
```

I am trying to get the row ID from the `doThis()` function like this:

```
function doThis(p) {
    alert(p);
}
```

Whenever the alert comes up, I get the following message:

```
[object HTMLTableRowElement]
```

What am I doing wrong? Why isn't it displaying the table ID instead?

What I am looking to do is for each row give me the value from each column on that given row...

How do I achieve that?

Comment: because you are not alerting `p.id`

Comment: ahhhhh damn it so simple, but shouldn't `p` be the value? Thanks! Would you happen to know how to cycle through each column for that ID and get the value of the column?

Comment: only if you pass `doThis` `whateverVariableHoldsRow.id`, edit: oh you are doing an onclick nevermind, Guffa's answer explains

Comment: @PatrickEvans Your solution also works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is ending up doing this (assuming i == 42):

```
onclick="doThis(itemEntry42);"
```

The expression `itemEntry42` is not a string, it evaluates to an identifier, which will be the element with `id="itemEntry42"`. The parameter `p` ends up being the element, not the id of the element.

You should use apostrophes around the id to make it a string literal instead of an identifier:

```
... onclick="doThis(\'' + rowId + '\');" ...
```

Comment: Thank you. Would you happen to know how to get each column value for that row with the ID?

Comment: @SiKni8: You would get all the columns inside the row, and get the text from each: `var values = $('#'+p+' td').map(function(i,c){ return $(c).text(); }).get();`

Comment: How does a variable name that just so happens to have a label the same as an ID value get turned into a DOM element reference simply by passing it to a function as an argument? I don't see anywhere that `itemEntry42` is equivalent to anything in a variable, except the string output in the `alert`. I've got to be missing something?

Comment: @JaredFarrish: The elements which have an id will be added as properties to the document object, at least in some browsers in some rendering modes. Evaluating the identifier gets the value of the property, which is the element, using it as a function parameter is not relevant for that part.

Comment: Thank you @Guffa it worked like a charm. Now I can use the .split() function to separate the values and use it for my need. Thanks again!

Comment: Oh you mean like this `document.itemEntry42` referencing `document.getElementById('itemEntry42')`? Similar to `document.images` and `document.forms`? Never knew that `id`s also did that.

Comment: @SiKni8: You don't need to use split, it's aleady an array.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: It's not so well known, as it's not the recommended way to access the elements. It's prone to naming conflicts with existing properties in the document, and any other identifier in scope.